# Why does playing sound/vibrating makes causes a crash?

Tags: ios

Im getting location updates from a locationManager with this method:

```
 - (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *) manager
 didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    for (CLLocation *p in taggedObjectsArray) {
         CLLocationDistance distance = [p  distanceFromLocation: newLocation];
         if(distance < 10.00){
             AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
             // if warning setting is set to sound, play sound
             if (beep) {
                 AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(beep);
             }
             [taggedObjectsArray removeObject:p];;
         }
    }
```

The taggedObjectsArray contains pointers to Cllocation objects

Now it works perfectly as long as there at not two objects in the array at any given run through the for loop. When there is two(or more) the app crashes after playing a single vibration.

Im guessing its because its trying to play a sound/beep on top of another sound/beep, but im not sure.

Anyone have a simple solution to this?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the crash say?

Comment: I don't think you should be removing objects from the array while iterating through it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with LuisCien that posting the contents of the debugger from the crash would be helpful.

One (blind) suggestion though would be to hold off on removing each object from `taggedObjectsArray` during each iteration of the loop and just do it after the fast enumeration completes with a single call to `[taggedObjectsArray removeAllObjects];`

from a pure efficiency and readability standpoint, it's cleaner to do this once with a stock method designed to remove everything than to invoke a single removal p times, since both end up with the same thing (an empty NSMutableArray)

There's a chance (speculation) that it might solve your crash too, but posting the crash log will help decide that better.

Comment: How do i get the crash log? in organizer i can find the "device logs" but it just shows a blank page. I have to remove one object at a time, or else i get multiple warnings for each location object until I'm 10m away again. But tell me how do i find my crash log. Im still new to iOS.

Comment: <Apple Shift Y> is the keyboard shortcut I use to show/hide the console, but there are a few other buttons scattered around to do it for you too. If you are showing the XCode toolbar, towards the very top right are three symbols that bring up various editors, the blue bar across the bottom is the debugger. **note that there are two sections in the debug area, console and variables. You may have to click the little split icons on the very bottom right to get the console to show.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x16e8d240> was mutated while being enumerated.' i guess that means you right

Comment: It's not right until it works, (and even then you should stay skeptical for a while). Did moving the calls to clear out the array outside of the fast enumeration loop get your code running with multi-element arrays?

Comment: I haven't tried it, because thats not the behavior i want. (maybe I'm not getting your point) i need to remove them right away or i get multiple warnings for each location! I googled the error message, and solved it by changing it to a regular for loop. Thanks a lot Ryan!

Comment: No worries, the important thing is you figured it out and got it working as you intended. Ultimately all that matters.